# How should I match the PATH?

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, module, path

I installed selenium by cmd but it doesn't work on Visual Studio Code Editor
I think I should match the PATH but I don't know how I should do it..

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\siwoo\Desktop\PythonWorkspace\new.py", line 1, in 
import selenium
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Comment: Can you show the way you import Selenium and the usage in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the Python environment you use in VS Code is different from the Python environment where the modules are installed in cmd.

Please use the command "`python --version`" in the cmd window to check the Python version, and use the command "`pip --version`" to check the source of the module installation tool pip, the module is installed in this location:

[image]

Then, we can use the command "`pip show selenium`" in VS Code to check whether its position is consistent with that in cmd:

[image]

(If it is inconsistent, please select the Python environment containing the module "selenium" in the lower left corner of VS Code, and then use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, and it will automatically enter this environment.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @tldn_0422 -I am glad that my answer helped you solve this problem. Please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install selenium on pip?

```
pip install selenium
```

Comment: yes I did. So the selenium works on cmd. However, it doesn't work on Visual Studio Code Editor.

Comment: I'm using selenium for web-crawling.

Comment: I import selenium to the script just by writing

Comment: import selenium

Comment: Did your python interpreter set correctly on visual studio code?

Comment: yeah. I bet I did.